How do constant-current drivers implement voltage limits?
Suppose I have a constant-current LED driver providing a stable 700mA between 8 and 10 volts. From my understanding, the current is kept the same (hence constant current) by increasing and decreasing the voltage, keeping LED brightness the same.
However, given a LED, or multiple LEDs in series/parallel, have a given \$V_{f}\$ and \$V_{f_{max}}\$, of which below \$V_{f}\$ the LED will not light, and anything above \$V_{f_{max}}\$ will destroy the LED, how are voltage limits implemented in a constant-current driver?

please fix your post

Current regulators work by monitoring current flow, and constantly raising or lowering their output voltage until the desired target current is achieved. These adjustments happen very quickly, and the output settles at an appropriate voltage almost instantly. Because they are measuring current, they do not need to know anything about their load. They do not need to be told what the target voltage is, the current source will find that value itself, by trial and error, using a negative feedback in a closed control loop. The rest of this answer explains these concepts in more detail.
An LED (or any two-terminal device) has some relationship between the current flowing through it, and the voltage appearing across it. You can specify (set) the voltage across it, and monitor what happens to current through it, or you can alter the current through it, and see how the voltage across it changes in response.
Below is an LED being powered by a current source (left), and the same LED being powered from a voltage source (right). The main point to note is that in both cases, the LED will pass the same current, and develop the same voltage, even though we are controlling voltage in one and current in the other:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
In the following two graphs, the first one shows how LED voltage varies when I explicitly "push" more and more current through it, and the second shows variation of LED current as I raise the voltage applied across it:


You can see that it doesn't matter what current or voltage I impose, conditions are identical in both cases. In particular, the green markers show the voltmeter and ammeter readings from the schematic, 1.754V and 5mA in both cases, whether as a result of explicitly applying a potential difference of 1.754V, or explicitly pushing 5mA through it.
The second point to take away here is that you may consider a current source to be an adjustable voltage source, that will produce whatever voltage is necessary to cause the load to pass exactly some desired current. In other words, it raises or lowers the voltage across it, forever adjusting that voltage, until the exact, required current is flowing.
This last description of a current source is what you are asking about: how does a current source know when to stop "raising" or "lowering" its voltage, to settle at exactly the correct voltage to pass, say, 5mA?
The solution is to measure current somehow, and adjust voltage across the LED until the target current is achieved. This can be performed in a number of ways. I will illustrate one such way, employing a resistor to measure current, and an op-amp with negative feedback to adjust voltage:

simulate this circuit
With negative feedback, an op-amp will equalise the potentials of its two inputs (inverting and non-inverting). By applying exactly \$V_{IN}=+1V\$ to the non-inverting input, I am telling the op-amp to produce whatever output potential \$V_{OUT}\$ is necessary to produce exactly \$V_Q=+1V\$ at Q, its other, inverting input. To do this, the op-amp must either raise or lower its output potential \$V_{OUT}\$.
Also, we can say that when this condition is reached, and \$V_Q=1V\$, then there will be 1V across resistor R1, and Ohm's law tells us the current that will be flowing:
$$ I = \frac{V_Q}{R_1} = \frac{1V}{200\Omega} = 5mA $$
In other words, by choosing \$R_1=200\Omega\$, and \$V_{IN}=1V\$, I am setting the conditions that must prevail, 5mA will be flowing.
If less than 5mA is flowing through R1, the voltage across the resistor will be less than 1V. In such circumstances, the op-amp must raise it's output, to increase \$V_Q\$. If more than 5mA is flowing, then \$V_Q\$ will exceed 1V, and the op-amp must lower \$V_{OUT}\$, in turn lowering \$V_Q\$.
The op-amp output must settle at the condition \$V_Q=V_{IN}=+1V\$, at which point (as we calculated above) current will be \$I=5mA\$. The schematic above shows this state, and you will notice that the voltage developed across the LED (shown on voltmeter VM1) is exactly what we predicted it should be: 1.754V. And yet we never told the system explicitly to produce 1.754V across the LED. We have permitted the LED to decide for itself what its voltage should be.
All we did was tell the op-amp what voltage (1V) to "aim for" across R1 (200Ω), and the result is that the op-amp, through trial and error, found that this condition is satisifed when \$V_{OUT}=+2.754V\$.
We have built a current source of 5mA. It is an adjustable voltage source, able to shift its output voltage up or down until the condition \$I=5mA\$ is met, which is exactly the description of a current source I wrote earlier.
You may change \$V_{IN}\$ or \$R_1\$ to set the target current. For instance, if I set \$V_{IN}=+2V\$, then \$V_Q\$ will also settle at +2V, and the current through R1 (and the LED) will be:
$$ \frac{V_{IN}}{R_1} = \frac{2V}{200\Omega} = 10mA $$

simulate this circuit
When 10mA passes through this LED, the voltage across it will no longer be 1.754V, which we can see from the graphs above. Now that voltage is 1.881V, but we never had to tell the circuit to aim for 1.881V across the LED. All we did is set target current to 10mA, and the diode again decided its own voltage. The op-amp then "found" the condition \$V_{OUT}=+3.881V\$ necessary to pass 10mA of current.
The above circuit is a very simple demonstration of current regulation, but it's not good for currents over 10mA or so. There are other ways to obtain higher currents, usually involving inductors and transformers, or beefy transistors, but the principle remains the same: An op-amp is used in a closed-loop, to measure current, and adjust the voltage across the load until some target current is flowing. In all cases, the load's voltage (under the condition where the exact required current is flowing) need not be known by the system. The closed-loop system is simply aiming for some target current to flow, and will produce whatever voltage is required for that to happen.

You may be confused by the "voltage limit" shown in driver datasheets. That limit is to protect the driver, not the LEDs. The LEDs are just fine with constant-current drive.
However, imagine you have a boost converter providing a constant current and you either put an excessive number of LEDs in series or open the connection to the LEDs entirely, even for a brief moment. Ideally, the voltage of a true constant-current would rise to maintain the current set, even if it had to arc across an open connection. However, a real boost converter has switches that have to block voltage when off and they can only handle so much voltage, so an open connection presents a danger to a constant-current boost converter. This is analogous to a constant voltage regulator that must be able to withstand a short circuit without failing to be acceptable in many applications.
So a constant-current switching driver will typically have some kind of nonlinear feedback that will at least limit the output voltage to a safe value if the output is left open. It is generally not a problem with linear constant-current regulators, since they can only output as much voltage as the input voltage.
For example, here is a datasheet for a constant-current boost converter LED driver chip from TI- typical application below. Note the 'extra' connection for OVP- the main regulation task is maintaining constant voltage (252mV nominally) across Rs. That means the LED current is controlled to a bit under 20mA when it is working properly.

The block diagram showing the 18V overvoltage protection is below:

As you can see, it's implemented with an internal 400mV reference, a voltage divider and a comparator.
There is also similarly implemented low input voltage protection (UVLO = undervoltage lockout) since the circuit could burn up if the MOSFET switches don't get enough gate voltage to fully turn on- and that's a pretty common situation as a battery dies, for example.

As you say, the LEDs have a low voltage limit for conducting a reasonable lighting current, or a high limit for conducting a damaging current.
These limits are not 'implemented' in the LED driver.
You have to choose a LED driver that has a specified voltage compliance that includes the range of operating voltages that the LEDs will set at the driver's nominal current.
The LED driver itself does not so much 'implement' the voltage limits, but has them by design. There are three simple (and many more not so simple) topologies, buck, boost and linear, each of which will have those high and voltage output constraints for different reasons.
Linear and buck simply cannot supply more voltage than they are supplied with, and usually a little less. Boost can potentially supply a very high voltage, so the output must be protected into an open circuit.
Linear may run into dissipation problems at the low output voltage end. Buck may have PWM duty cycle or stability problems at a low output voltages. At voltages below its input voltage, a simple boost converter is uncontrolled, the input feeds the output directly via the inductor and a diode.
Any of these over/under voltage outputs may cause a safety shutdown, or it may just persist, depending on the specifications of the particular driver and the design of any detection logic.
